Is 0-1 knapsack problem still NP-Hard (1) with an equality constraint and (2) when all the weights in the constraint are equal to one?
Is 0-1 knapsack problem still NP-Hard with an equality constraint?
$$\begin{aligned}
& \text { maximize } \sum_{i=1}^n v_i x_i \\
& \text { subject to } \sum_{i=1}^n w_i x_i = W \text { and } x_i \in\{0,1\} \text {. }
\end{aligned}$$
What if $w_i=1$ for all $i = \{1,\dots,n\}$? Is 0-1 knapsack problem still NP-Hard when all the weights in the constraint are equal to one?
$$\begin{aligned}
& \text { maximize } \sum_{i=1}^n v_i x_i \\
& \text { subject to } \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = W \text { and } x_i \in\{0,1\} \text {. }
\end{aligned}$$

If you solve the LP relaxation with the simplex algorithm you will get a binary solution. So clearly the problem is not NP hard.

I believe it is still NP-hard with the equality constraints. link

I assumed w_i=1 and W is positive integer. Any feasible basic solution must be an integer feasible solution IMO.

Please ask only one question per post.  It appears you added an entirely different question at the end in revision 3.  Can you say more about the reasons for that revision?

I was thinking about using the knapsack problem to prove the NP-hardness of the problem I have. The constraint $|S_t| \leq K$ can be seen as an inequality constraint with all weights that are equal to one.

With equality constraint, the problem can be solved in polynomial time. With inequality constraint, the time complexity in the worst case to solve is in exponential time.

The general case where not all weights are equal to one, is ${NP}$ hard, as the subset sum problem reduces to it with a constant objective function.
If all weights $w_i$ are equal to one, the problem can be solved in ${O}(n\log (n))$ time, as you can solve the problem $\max\{v^Tx:\mathbf{1}^Tx=W, x\in\{0,1\}^n\}$ by sorting the items in non-increasing order of $v_i$ and then set $x_i=1$ for the first $W$ items, and $x_i=0$ for the remaining $n-W$ items.

Thank you! This is very informative. I have two related questions. (1) Is the problem still NP-hard if all weights $w_i$ are equal to one but with an inequality constraint? (I think it is still NP-hard as the subset sum problem reduces to it.) (2) I have a problem that I know the time complexity in the worst case to solve is in exponential time but I had a hard time coming up with a NP-hard proof for it. Do you have any suggestions? (Just updated the problem in this post).

To answer (1): You solve the inequality variant, $\max{v^Tx:\mathbf{1}^Tx \leq W, x\in{0,1}^n}$, much the same way. Among the W first items, you just only choose the subset of items with positve value, $v_i > 0$, as they are the ones that increase the objective value.

Got it! Thanks.
